# How do you select an edge loop with BMesh?

Tags: scripting, edges, bmesh

Can someone please explain to me how I go about selecting edge loops in BMesh? I'm new to Blender scripting and am venturing into BMesh but I can not figure out how to actual select an edge loop. Let's say I'm starting with an edge. How then do I go about getting and selecting the edge loop that that edge is a part of? Please and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79995/30849). Simply add the select statement at the end. I also branched the code sample to go in both directions of the first edge.

```
e = bm.edges[0]

for loop in e.link_loops:
    if len(loop.vert.link_edges) == 4:
        e.select = True

        while len(loop.vert.link_edges) == 4:
            # jump between BMLoops to the next BMLoop we need
            loop = loop.link_loop_prev.link_loop_radial_prev.link_loop_prev

            # following edge in the edge loop
            e_next = loop.edge
            e_next.select = True
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I saw that one but for some reason I couldn't ever get it to work let alone how it actually works.