# Make a 3d line on Object

Tags: modeling, texturing

i wantd to make a "line" around the model. The only solution i found is to select the edges for the line and press "s" to put them more into the model. But then i need to select every single edge left and right on that "line" to put them more together to get that "deep" effect. Is there an easier solution to do that? It does not only take alot of time to select and move every edge the bigger problem is that the edges arent all at the same spot to have a smove line.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions

Comment: could you make another screenshot or draw something to make it clearer please?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [smoothing an edgeloop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110361/30849) and the shrink/fatten tool (Alt S).

Comment: I did edited my post with more pictures, maybe its more clear now @moonboots

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is what Nicola Sap shows, here is another way to do it, pretty close, but with the Bevel tool:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your edge loop is clean (*i.e.* you can go around your "ring" by walking only along quadrilateral faces) you can use loop cuts:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, find the correct area (pink line), <kbd>LMB</kbd> to accept the region, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the position

   [image]

   (this creates the line that will be then "buried")
2. Same as before, to the right and to the left of the middle line. This time, though, slide the "line preview" to make it closer to the centre line before accepting (<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

   [image]

   (Alternatively you can <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> select the middle line then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to make two lines around it)
3. deselect all (<kbd>A</kbd>), then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the middle line, and finally <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it inwards

   [image]

   [image]

---

P.S. instead of making 3 cuts and shrinking the middle one, you can also make 2 cuts and shrink (<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) the faces between them. I personally suggest this method.

[image]